# What is the opposite of heritage?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

According to the definition I'm aware of, heritage means "something that will be inherited by the subject". So if a person A leaves an item X for person B in his will, X is B's heritage.

Is there a word that means "something left by the subject to be inherited by someone else"?
(To be used as "X is A's [ something ]").

Comment: Heritage is slightly different than inheritance. However, inheritance (or heritage) has no opposite. You either inherit something or you don't. It's not like you could give something to someone upon that someone's death, it's always the other way around.

Comment: Obviously, it's `hisitage`.   Kids these days.

Comment: What is wrong with inheritance?

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17769/what-is-the-difference-between-legacy-and-inheritance

Comment: @CPerkins: you may have the genders the wrong way round: if *patrimony* is another word for *heritage*, then its opposite should be *matrimony* or *marriage* (and *-age* is a real suffix)

Comment: @CPerkins - I would have said *himitage*.

Comment: The definition of *heritage* that I'm aware of: "valued objects and qualities such as cultural traditions, unspoiled countryside, and historic buildings that have been passed down from previous generations." –G. Why is A's thing not B's inheritance?

Comment: @Henry I don't think I'm confused.  I'm pretty sure that "her" and "his" are opposites across the gender inflection, hence "heritage" and "hisitage".

Comment: @CPerkins Her gets used in a few places where his doesn't. The counter part of "That's his!" is "That's hers!", not "That's her!".  Also as an object: "I like her"/"I like him" (not "I like his").  So her/his is fine for "her car"/"his car", but different in the other cases.

Comment: @Mazura A's x is B's inheritance indeed (or it will be, when A dies). The question is, knowing that, what does A call x? "X is A's [blank]"

Comment: You have defined "inheritance", not "heritage". Heritage is what our forefathers created which we get to enjoy as soon as we are born. Inheritance is their property which they pass on to us when they die. Neither has a clear opposite. I suppose we could contrast heritage with things newly created and things inherited with things won in the sweat of one's brow.

Comment: *500 point bounty* @DavidC

Comment: Heirloom? Well...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Legacy

["A thing handed down by a predecessor" - OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/legacy)

Comment: Not sure what meaning of "opposite" you're using here...

Comment: @Mehrdad: "Opposite" is a nearly meaningless word. Look at the last sentences of the original post: "Is there a word that means "something left by the subject to be inherited by someone else"? (To be used as "X is A's [ something ]")."

Comment: Yeah... opposite is the only word I could come up with to describe what I wanted in a concise way.  But whether or not that was a good choice of words, I think legacy is what I was looking for.

Comment: @leinaD_natipaC perhaps "complement" would have worked better.

Comment: Should I open a question on how to ask this question?

Answer (score 36):

I like Chris's suggestion, "legacy", but another synonym that fits might be "**bequest**", which is defined in simple terms by [Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bequest) as

> the property or money that you promise in your will to give to another
>   person or organization after you die

Comment: "bequest" is too narrowly defined for the purpose of serving as an antonym to heritage.

Comment: @Aaron I don't think so. I think it's what I asked for, but even then legacy fits the bill better.

Comment: @leinaD_natipaC It absolutely isn't what you want. Heritage is a broad concept that includes reputation, tradition, and to avoid being redundant to wikipedia, see the list at the top of this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heritage A bequest is property willfully given (usually so directed in a legal document). Heritage is so much more than that. Even an inheritance is not necessarily a bequest - one may inherit property as dictated by state law in contradiction to a decedent's will.

Comment: @AaronHall Well. Despite what you want me to want, it answers the general intention (remember, the text of the question *is* the question), and anyway the definition is included to make it unambiguous. So if you want to get pedantic, then it's still what I asked for.

Comment: Yeah, you had a messed up definition of heritage that you didn't even bother to look up.

Answer (score 12):

"Something left by the subject to be inherited by someone else" is called the [estate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/estate), especially in legal documents.

E.g. *The late Mrs A's house is part of her estate*

Comment: I thought it meant something more akin to "property", or land based property as in real estate.

Comment: @leinaD_natipaC: That's another, separate meaning.

Comment: I believe the estate of someone deceased consists of all of the property of that person, to be divvied up according to their will, prevailing law, etc...it's not precisely an antonym, as it initially includes the inheritances of all parties, but it is probably the most useful word among the answers here, since, you could say "Her daughter X inherited the family business, while the remainder of the estate was given to charity"; it does give you an easy way to discuss the portion of someone's estate not inherited by a specific person.

Answer (score -3):

#### Chattels

- **Heritage** is essentially the non-portable parts of one's legacy (land, buildings, etc)
- **Chattels** refers to the portable goods and money.

I'm not sure how non-physical assets such as heritable titles or intellectual property are classified.

Comment: Chattels are movable (and alienable) property in general, with no implication of legacy.

Comment: Consider the phrase: "*My heritage is ...*" -- Heritage also includes such **intangibles** as *birthright* (for instance titles of nobility) and *family history* (the legend of great grandpappy's moonshine business). It also includes ethnic history or pride (Anglo, Jewish, Black, etc). Since it is possible in to give away or sell one's birthright, some parts of heritage are also "portable" (or more correctly "transferable") and in other cases (like naratives) [*replicable*](http://www.yourdictionary.com/replicable).